# list files that do not contain pattern anywhere in filename (zsh only)

Tags: zsh

Say I have a list of files in dir like so:

```
blackneasy-sq.png
dima-sq.png
envoy-sq.png
fox-sq.png
freeze-sq.png
ministarstvo kulture-sq.png
naxi-sq.png
pick-sq.png
pink-sq.png
wink-sq.png
brick-sq.png
rider-sq.png
sixt-rent-a-car.png
slavija hotel-sq.png
temet-sq.png
tepe-sq.png
```

How would I specify exclude pattern to show all files except those that
contain `ck` chars glued together anywhere in filename?

So in a resulting list, files:

```
blackneasy-sq.png
pick-sq.png
brick-sq.png
```

should not be shown.

I tried this without success.

```
print -l [[:alpha:]]*^ck*.*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `~` operator: `THIS~THAT` matches files that match the pattern `THIS` but not `THAT`. This requires the `extended_glob` option (which is automatically turned on in some contexts such as completion function, but is not the default state).

```
print -l -- *.png~*ck*
```

You can abbreviate `*~THAT` to `^THAT` (also requiring `extended_glob`), so if you don't want to limit to `.png` files, you can use

```
print -l -- ^*ck*
```

Comment: Is there a way for `[[:alpha:]]` not to be eager with `*` or `#` or does it always consume as much as possible!?

Comment: @branquito `*` and `#` are always eager. But eagerness only matters when you have capture group, not with regex matching alone.

Comment: Also being curious, if it weren't for `THIS~THAT`, would it be possible to do this some other way without help of grep or whatever? Thanks

Comment: @branquito `grep` would be hard to use for that unless you know that your file names can't contain any special characters. The plain sh way of doing this is `for x in *.png; do case "$x" in *ck*) continue;; esac; {process $x}; done`

Comment: But why my `[[:alpha:]]*^ck` didn't work as expected?

Comment: @branquito `[[:alpha:]]*^ck` matches anything that starts with a letter and ends with something that isn't `ck`. Since `ck` can be matched by `*`, `[[:alpha:]]*^ck` matches anything that starts with a letter. Eagerness wouldn't help: they still *allow* the star to match as long as it wants, eagerness is just a matter of preference when there are several possible ways to match.